# How to get the absolute path of a local file on Drag and drop?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to figure out how to get the local path (file:///C:/test.jpg) of a file that has been dropped over a specific element on a webpage. It's the only information I need but everything I found on the internet is about uploading a file.

It's for a basic PHP script running on a local WAMP server.

Is it possible ?
How can I do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what are you expecting to do with local file path? Can't get it from browser but perhaps knowing your goals there might be a workaround

Comment: It's to add file infos to a sqlite DB using getID3 PHP class. As I said, it only running on 1 single local computer with EasyPHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just upload the image to WAMP server and set the path with your php. You will end up with duplicate files but will get around security issues

Comment: Yeah I though about that, but I'm not sure yet. If I don't find any other solution I think I'm going to do it that way. Thanks Charlietfl.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible ? How can I do this?

No, of course not. For security reasons you cannot get the full path of a file on the client computer. You, as a web developer, are absolutely not supposed to know anything about the folder structure of your client computers. You could of course get the contents of the file that has been dropped into your webpage, but that's as far as you would get.

If you need to so much know where is this file stored on your clients computers you could provide an input field and simply ask them to give you this information. But without their explicit consent this is not possible.

Comment: It's not for a client, it's for my mother LOL and it take more times to copy&paste (for someone like her) than a drag and drop. Well, Thanks for your explanation. :) Happy holidays